# "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account."-Rule too strong?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

https://stackoverflow.com/users/852592/mcb?tab=reputation

Maybe I was just a bit unlucky: I got some down votes, one questions has been moved to Ask Different and another question has been closed as exact duplicate (and it's even not a duplicate!) and now I'm banned to ask questions.

Since it's of course impossible for me to determine the number of cases which are similar to mine I can't say if it's true: but in my opinion the question ban rule is a bit too strong.

Comment: Have any of your questions been deleted, mcb? By you or others. Downvotes on those also count against you. By the way, you should not have deleted the automatically-generated duplicate link. I've added it back in.

Comment: Hm. I don't think so. I only once or twice removed my answer because it was obsolet, but it had no down votes (as far as I remember). 5 people considered my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772848/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-save-an-array-to-sql-than-php-function-serialize) to be a duplicate. Maybe that causes the ban?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that last question. It's generally thought that the ban is influenced only by downvotes (not close votes, for instance).

Comment: Ok, that answered that last question.

Comment: You also had one question ("Does stackoverflow have any patents on their Q/A system") that was downvoted three times and deleted.  I know deleted questions are a factor, but I don't know the exact algorithm.  The best thing you can do is edit your existing posts to improve them and try and get some upvotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- you are asking off-topic, end user, non-programming-related questions about how OS X works (two so far)
- you asked an egregiously off-topic question titled "Does stackoverflow have any patents on their Q/A system?"
- several of your remaining questions are basically bikeshed, opinion questions (which is better, chocolate code or vanilla code?)

I removed ownership of the patent question which was at -3 and deleted.

But fair warning, you REALLY REALLY need to read https://stackoverflow.com/faq and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask closely. Otherwise you're likely to be blocked again very soon, because you are skirting the edge of what we consider viable here with many of your questions.

Comment: I have to admit that I never read the FAQs. Sorry for that! And thanks for removing the ownership.